# Any way to get details about the SSL Certificate from fetch response (NodeJS)?

Tags: node.js, fetch, ssl-certificate

I've been trying to get SSL Certificate details from a fetch request (HTTPS); but I haven't been able to figure out a way to pull that data out. Does fetch just not have that data available?

Was also looking at Axios, which seemed more promising, but the only way I could see the cert details was to enable tracing, which just dumped the data in console.

Here's an example:

```
const response = await fetch('https://some.url');

// how do I get the certificate details from this? (i.e. start, end date)
const cert = response.certificate() // this would be nice
```

Comment: I know I can make another request using a library specifically designed to get the cert, but it seems redundant. I should be able to get it from the initial request.